# Set grid column or grid row in C# code behind

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-8.1

I have set `ColumnDefinitions` in XAML like:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid"  Background="#FF256BD1">
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
 <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

...
</Grid>
```

In the code behind I'm adding a `StackPanel` as children in the `MainGrid` like:

```
MainGrid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
```

How to put this stackPanel in the First Column in Code behind like we do in XAML as: `Grid.Column="0"` or `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"` or `Grid.Row="1"`, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make use of the `SetRow`, `SetColumn`, `SetColumnSpan` Methods:

```
Grid.Children.Add(stackPanel);
Grid.SetRow(stackPanel, 1);
Grid.SetColumn(stackPanel, 0);
Grid.SetColumnSpan(stackPanel, 2);
```